# Django Python shows me strange results if I use fetchall() command

Tags: python, django

I used Django framework and MySQL database. I tired to show full names in a row, and it shows me encoded results on the html page like below. I tried to put decode option on python, but it didn't work well. If I use fetchone() command, it shows a correct word. However, it shows me different result if I use fetchall() command. Can you see the errors?

**profile.py**

```
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT full_name FROM myapp_profile ORDER BY idx DESC")
results = cursor.fetchall()

x = cursor.description
resultsList = []   
for r in results:
    i = 0
    d = {}
    while i < len(x):
        d[x[i][0]] = r[i]
        i = i+1
    resultsList.append(d)

context = Context({'data' : resultsList })
return HttpResponse(loader.get_template('profile/profile_list.html').render(context))
```

**result on html**

```
{'full_name': u'\uae40\uc9c0\uc120'} 
{'full_name': u'\uc774\uc8fc\ud604'} 
{'full_name': u'\uae40\uae30\uc790'} 
{'full_name': u'\uae40\uae30\uc131'} 
{'full_name': u'\uae40\uc544\uc601'}
```

Comment: Why don't you use the model layer?

Answer (score 0):

html code was wrong..

it was like this before..

```
{% if data %}
   There are {{ data|length }} records:
   {% for e in data %}
      <br />
      <td> {{ e }} </td>
      <br />
   {% endfor %}
{% else %}
   There are no records in the system
{% endif %}
```

I changed it like this, and it worked

```
{% if data %}
   There are {{ data|length }} records:
   {% for e in data %}
      <br />
      <td> {{ e.full_name }} </td>
      <br />
   {% endfor %}
{% else %}
   There are no records in the system
{% endif %}
```